# Reading from a File to an array

Tags: c++

I have the code bellow that populates an array and prints the array out, it then prints the array out in reverse order.  My question is now that I have done that, how can I instead of populating the list from a loop, populate it from a file instead?

Code:

```
void popArray(int array1[]){
  for(int x = 0; x < 10; x++){
    array1[x] = x;
    cout << setw(2) << array1[x];
  }
}

void reverseList(int array1[]){
  for(int x = 9; x > -1; x--){
    cout << setw(2) << array1[x];
  }
}


int main()
{
  int array1[9];

  popArray(array1);

  cout << "\n";

  reverseList(array1);
}
```

Comment: What is the file format? By the way, you are accessing outside the bounds of the array. I think you want an array of size 10, so it should be `int array1[10];`.

Comment: lookup `std::ifstream` there are tons of examples and documentation.

Comment: Is the file binary or do you want to read one line at a time, convert the string to an integer and then store it into the array?

Comment: @CaptainObvlious The file will just be one that is made in .txt format.

Comment: What exactly do you want? Information how to read a file into an array? Or how to print out file content in reverse order? BTW, there is no list in your code, you only have an array.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you are planning to have the numbers in your file.
You could have one integer each on a line and keep on reading the file until the end or you could have csv values. 
You could then read the file in the popArray function.
Below is some reference on reading a file: 
http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/

If you plan to use one integer on each line of the file, below is something you could use.

```
void popArray(int array1[], std::string filename) {
    ifstream myfile (filename);
    while ( myfile.good() )
    {
        std::string line;

        getline (myfile,line);
        array1[x] = atoi(line.c_str());
        cout << line << endl;
    }
    myfile.close();
}
```